# Integration R and C++

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile, rcpp

I  use R version 2.15.3. I want in  my C++ program library Rcpp.h. How to tell the compiler where is the library? I use utilyty make:

```
    CC=g++
    LDFLAGS=$(shell Rscript -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()")
    CFLAGS=$(shell Rscript -e "Rcpp:::CxxFlags()")
    SOURCES=src/main.cpp
    OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

    myrcpp : $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) $(OBJECTS) myrcpp
    main.o : $(SOURCES)
        $(CC) -o  $(LDFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(SOURCES) 
    clean : 
        rm myrcpp $(OBJECTS)
```

but i have error, compiler don't find Rcpp.h

Comment: What does `shell Rscript -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()"` and `shell Rscript -e "Rcpp:::CxxFlags()"` actually produce? That should give a `-I<something that contains Rcpp.h` (along with, quite possibly, some other stuff).

Comment: shell Rscript -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()" should give:
 -L/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/lib -lRcpp -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/lib

and shell Rscript -e "Rcpp:::CxxFlags()":
-I/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include

Answer (score 1):

`Rcpp` is for embedding C++ code in R. If this is what you want to do, you can learn about making an R package that uses `Rcpp` by reading documentation from the package.

If what you want to do is to make a C++ application that uses `Rcpp`, you need to look at `RInside` and its many documented examples.